# How to use template variables in group_vars

Tags: ansible

In `group_vars/`, I have three files corresponding to inventory group names:

- `all.yml`
- `windows.yml`
- `linux.yml`

In `windows.yml` I define `bot-os-user: MYDOMAIN\domainuser`.

In `linux.yml` I define `bot-os-user: somelinuxuser`.

In `all.yml` I define `ansible_user: {{ bot-os-user }}`.

Problem is, specified like that, Ansible tells me `{{ ... }}` should be in double quotes. And with double quotes, the `{{ bot-os-user }}` never gets expanded, i.e. it literally stays `{{ bot-os-user }}`, whereas expected result is `ansible_user` having the value of `bot-os-user`'s variable.

Am I missing something? How do I make it work?

P.S. It's really about reusing variables to define other variables values and not something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems. See the notes below. In addition to this, the issue here is the definition of variables, hence I've renamed  *ansible_user* from the question to *my_ansible_user*.

- Expansion of a variable must be quoted and variable *bot_os_user* must exist.

  my_ansible_user: "{{ bot_os_user }}"
- Variable *bot_os_user* will exist if any, or both, of the files *windows.yml*, linux.yml are included in a play
- The file *windows.yml*, or *linux.yml* from the directory group_vars/ will be included if the host, running the play, is a member of the group *windows*, or *linux*.

For example:

```
> cat group_vars/linux.yml
bot_os_user: "linux-user"

> cat group_vars/all.yml
my_ansible_user: "{{ bot_os_user }}"

> cat hosts
---
linux:
  hosts:
    test_01:
    test_02:
    test_03:
```

The play below

```
> cat test1.yml
---
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - debug: var=bot_os_user
    - debug: var=my_ansible_user
```

gives:

```
ok: [test_01] => {
"bot_os_user": "linux-user"
ok: [test_01] => {
"my_ansible_user": "linux-user"
}
```

Notes:

- "-" is not a valid character in the name of a variable
- Correct name of the directory is *group_vars*
- Avoid escape characters "\" in text if possible

Comment: `groups_vars` was my typo, it's actually called `group_vars` properly on the filesystem, thanks for catching that. Yes, invalid characters in variable names were the cause.